# Unable to open PyCharm IDE on Mac -StartupAbortedException

Tags: macos, pycharm, jetbrains-ide

I am new to PyCharm IDE and Mac. When I try to open PyCharm the below exception is thrown:

> Java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: com.intellij.ide.plugins.StartupAbortedException : cannot create file types.

I have already installed IntelliJ also.  I searched but couldn't find a solution for this specific exception.

- MacOs - Catalina 10.15.7
- PyCharm - Community 2021.1

How can I sort out this issue, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you:

- Restarted (your computer)
- Reinstalled (pycharm)
- Reinstalled (JetBrains toolbox)

Are you using JetBrains toolbox to install?

Comment: Thanks. I restarted the laptop and didn't work.  Btw I don't use toolbox. Just downloaded and drag to Applications and open it.

Comment: did it work? if it did then I would assume this the answer?  

Answer (score 0):

I have reinstalled 2020 community version. Now working fine.